# Erro ao rodar o comando "npm run prod" no Git Bash para dar Build em um projeto Ionic 2

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic2, npm, angular

Estou com um projeto pronto para publicação, o qual foi criado com Ionic 2 utilizando API do Firebase do Google, porém quando tento buildar o projeto para produção, com o seguinte comando no Git Bash: "npm run prod", é exibido um erro no qual não consegui identificar.
Segue o erro abaixo:

```
$ npm run prod

> Ionic2FirebaseChat@0.0.1 prod C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat
> ionic-app-scripts build --prod

[16:17:40]  ionic-app-scripts 3.0.0
[16:17:40]  build prod started ...
[16:17:42]  clean started ...
[16:17:42]  clean finished in 117 ms
[16:17:42]  copy started ...
[16:17:42]  deeplinks started ...
[16:17:42]  deeplinks finished in 177 ms
[16:17:42]  ngc started ...
[16:18:14]  ngc finished in 31.45 s
[16:18:14]  preprocess started ...
[16:18:14]  copy finished in 32.34 s
[16:18:14]  preprocess finished in 285 ms
[16:18:14]  webpack started ...
[16:19:07]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[16:19:07]  Error: ./models/chat.model.ts Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
            'C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\models\chat.model.js' at Error (native) @ ./src/pages/home/home.ts
            10:0-50 @ ./src/pages/sign/sign.ts @ ./src/components/base.component.ts @
            ./src/components/user-menu/user-menu.component.ts @ ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts @
            ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts,./models/message.model.ts Module build failed: Error:
            ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\models\message.model.js'
            at Error (native) @ ./src/pages/chat/chat.ts 4:0-56 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @
            ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts,./models/user.model.ts Module build failed: Error:
            ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\models\user.model.js' at
            Error (native) @ ./src/components/user-menu/user-menu.component.ts 6:0-50 @
            ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts
Error: ./models/chat.model.ts
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\models\chat.model.js'
    at Error (native)
 @ ./src/pages/home/home.ts 10:0-50
 @ ./src/pages/sign/sign.ts
 @ ./src/components/base.component.ts
 @ ./src/components/user-menu/user-menu.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./models/message.model.ts
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\models\message.model.js'
    at Error (native)
 @ ./src/pages/chat/chat.ts 4:0-56
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./models/user.model.ts
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\models\user.model.js'
    at Error (native)
 @ ./src/components/user-menu/user-menu.component.ts 6:0-50
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
    at BuildError.Error (native)
    at new BuildError (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at callback (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack.js:123:28)
    at emitRecords.err (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:222:13)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "prod"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Ionic2FirebaseChat@0.0.1 prod: `ionic-app-scripts build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Ionic2FirebaseChat@0.0.1 prod script 'ionic-app-scripts build --prod'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the Ionic2FirebaseChat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build --prod
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs Ionic2FirebaseChat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls Ionic2FirebaseChat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\apps\ionic2\Ionic2FirebaseChat\npm-debug.log
```

Minhas configurações da aplicação são estas:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v6.11.4
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente rodar **`npm run production`** ao invés de `npm run prod`.

Pode ser a versão do Node.js... Atualize a versão com o comando: `npm update -g`.

Comment: Rodei o comando para atualização do node.js, e tentei rodar o comando npm run production ao invés de npm run prod. Mas não deu certo também, exibindo erros de npm ERR!, muito semelhantes ao do comando recente "npm run prod".

Comment: Achei meu erro. Tratava-se de uma pasta que criei de código fora da pasta destinada a tal, a "src".
Passei esta para a pasta correta e o Build funcionou corretamente.
De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo auxílio.